# How do I PUT JSON data to Ruby on Rails using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I am trying to send a jQuery Ajax PUT request that looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "PUT",
      url: '/admin/pages/1.json',
      data: { page : {...} },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(msg) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      }
});
```

My controller looks roughly like this:

```
      respond_to do |format|
         if @page.update_attributes params[:page]
           format.html{ ... }
           format.json{ render :json => {:saved => 'ok'}.to_json }
         else
           format.html{ ... }
           format.json{ render :json => {:saved => 'fail'}.to_json }
         end
       end
```

but I get the following error.

The error occurred while evaluating nil.name
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/xml_mini/rexml.rb:29:in `merge_element!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/xml_mini/rexml.rb:18:in`parse'
    (**DELEGATION**):2:in `__send__'
    (__DELEGATION__):2:in`parse'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions.rb:154:in `from_xml'
...
...

It is like Ruby on Rails is trying to parse the parameters as XML, but I want to use JSON!

What shall I do to put JSON to Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Update your original question by editing it instead of asking a new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907910/how-do-i-put-data-to-rails-using-jquery

Answer (score 7):

Setting the contentType didn't work for me. I was getting a string instead of a hash for params[:page].

So I solved it like this:

Stringifying the JSON object with a script found at *JSON in JavaScript*:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: '/admin/pages/1.json',
    data: { page : JSON.strigify( {...} ) },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});
```

On the Ruby on Rails side, a JSON gem must be required. In the controller:

```
 params[:page] = JSON.parse params[:page] if params[:page].is_a? String
```

It is not pretty at all, but it worked for me.

Comment: Be careful with this - PUT isn't supported by all browsers. Some only do GET and POST, I'm not sure which.

Comment: Parsing will be done automatically by Rails if you set the contentType. See my response

Answer (score 5):

You need to set contentType in your options. contentType is what you are sending. dataType is what you expect back. You should carefully read the [documentation on the options argument to ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options).

Comment: data also needs to be serialized. See my answer

Answer (score 2):

Also, head's up, but there's a bug in Ruby on Rails 2.3.2 that prevents this from working. See *[Ruby on Rails 2.3 JSON "put" request routing is broken](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2448-rails-23-json-put-request-routing-is-broken)*

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to add scripts, you could do

```
$.parseJSON("some_jsonish_string")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `contentType` to `"application/json"` in your options; `dataType` is only what you expect back.

Also, you need to serialize your `data` field using `JSON.stringify`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: '/admin/pages/1.json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ page :  {...} }),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
})
```