# How should I port this Prototype to JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

There is currently this Prototype code that does a PUT:

```
new Ajax.Request(someUrl, {
    method: 'put',
    parameters: { 'foo': bar },
    onSuccess: function(response) { } .bind(this)
});
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907910/how-do-i-put-data-to-rails-using-jquery) but the solution uses an extra parameter supported by RoR, however I am targeting an ASP.NET backend.

I searched a bit and found that not all browsers support PUT operations so apparently this could fail in certain browsers?  This is already in prod, so a direct port would be fine for now I suppose.

As an aside, what is the deal with the bind(this) in the onSuccess function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.bind(this)` returns a wrapper function that calls the original function in the context of the parameter passed to `.bind`.

You can port the code using [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: someUrl,
    type: 'put',
    data: { foo: bar},
    context: this,        //Calls callback in context.
    success: function() { }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`put` and `delete` requests map to the jQuery `$.ajax` function ([here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)).

```
$.ajax(
    url: someUrl,
    type: 'put',
    data: { /* your key-value data pairs here */ },
    success: function() {
        alert('put request succeeded!');
    }
);
```