# Fine Grained rest HTTP verbs browser support

Tags: http, rest, cross-browser, http-method

Is there any data regarding how browsers actually support rest http verbs (especially PUT, DELETE). This question is mostly motivated by the fact that many sources (such as this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907910/how-do-i-put-data-to-rails-using-jquery/907974#907974)) inform that most browsers don't suport PUT and DELETE but don't say which.

[Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-put-or-delete-methods-work) solves this using a patch on the client, and reversing the patch on the server, but I wonder, for instance, which browsers wouldn't need such hack.

Comment: What does this have to do with the browsers?

Comment: Jonh: Several of them can't perform PUT DELETE queries. This is mostly important in ajax queries, as good old forms can't do this by spec. Also, on restful webservices, the semantics behind PUT and DELETE matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in doubt, [ask Anne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171994/337079):

http://annevankesteren.nl/2007/10/http-method-support

It's a couple of years old, but it gives a clean bill of health to PUT and DELETE, but it also tries different cases of more obscure verbs like TRACE and PROPFIND:

Van Kesteren tested Firefox 3, Opera 9.5 and Internet Explorer 7, a mix of pre-release and releases.  GET and POST worked as expected, and all supported the standard set of http methods from RFC 2616.  There are some casing issues, so you should try to stick with uppercase always; TRACE and OPTIONS are edge cases with problems found in Firefox and Opera, respectively. CONNECT and TRACE and SEARCH are problematic for IE.  Bear in mind that this was written in 2007 so YMMV.

I think the whole confusion over browsers not supporting other than GET and POST stems from the fact that the HTML specification lists *only* these two in the [HTML `<form>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1):

> The method attribute of the FORM element specifies the HTTP method used to send the form to the processing agent. This attribute may take two values:
>
> - get: With the HTTP "get" method, the form data set is appended to the URI specified by the action attribute (with a question-mark ("?") as separator) and this new URI is sent to the processing agent.
> - post: With the HTTP "post" method, the form data set is included in the body of the form and sent to the processing agent.

This is the reason why browsers only support GET and POST natively in HTML; since the standard says so.

The current (January 2014) [XMLHttpRequest specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open%28%29-method) on the other hand states explicitly that request methods should be allowed through with some exceptions (CONNECT, TRACE or TRACK), and that RFC2616 methods should be uppercased:

> \6. If method is a case-insensitive match for CONNECT, DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT, TRACE, or TRACK, subtract 0x20 from each byte in the range 0x61 (ASCII a) to 0x7A (ASCII z).
>
> > *If it does not match any of the above, it is passed through literally, including in the final request.*

**EDIT** Another source that has come to more or less the same conclusion:  That XMLHttpRequest supports PUT and DELETE:  http://jshirley.vox.com/library/post/xmlhttprequest-and-rest.html (warning, broken link as of May 2014).

**EDIT** The question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers) of course, but the two year old answers are still valid.

**EDIT** Short resume of Anne van Kesteren's page from 2007, and added section on HTML vs XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Yes, it is old. But then, i guess it is sadly, the best we have, without crowdsourcing people into http://www.mnot.net/javascript/xmlhttprequest/

Comment: Anne Van Kesteren's link is dead. When answering with sources from other sites, you should transcribe them here to avoid losing the information when links go dead. :(

Comment: In principle, I have to agree. In my defence the sources were already three full years old when I cited them, and tested then-current versions of browsers. Now they are 7 years old.  I found the AVK link working fine, but jshirley on the other hand gave me a blank stare. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @AlejandroIglesias I hope you find my edits to your satisfaction :-)

Answer (score -1):

See the [PutDeleteSupport](http://www.intertwingly.net/wiki/pie/PutDeleteSupport) page of the Atom Wiki. You might be interested in browsing other Atom Wiki pages related to HTTP.

Comment: Thanks, but this one actually only show the support on language clients. I am looking for the support on browser clients, such as chorme, firefox, ie, opera, opera mini, and so on.