# Is There a Table That Shows HTTP Method Support by Browser

Tags: http, cross-browser, http-method

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)

I've seen lots of stuff that generally say "not all browser support all HTTP methods" etc., but is there a nice table that shows specifically which HTTP methods are support that's broken down by browser?

I see this previous question on SO but it's not the answer I'm looking for:
[Fine Grained rest HTTP verbs browser support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218053/fine-grained-rest-http-verbs-browser-support)

Comment: It appears to answer your question, specifically: *it gives a clean bill of health to PUT and DELETE* (and of course GET).  Perhaps you could be a bit more specific?

Comment: Yeah, and I acknowledged so, but has this been answered? Is there such a table or not?

Comment: Duplicate of which question?

Answer (score 3):

As of now, all browsers except IE have been fixed to support arbitrary methods. IE9 will do when in standards mode. Earlier IEs can use all methods if you use the XMLHttpRequest Active-X object (instead of the native Javascript one).

Comment: Are you serious? the newer native JavaScript XMLHTTPRequest object has less support in IE? - wow that is messed up!

Comment: scunliffe, indeed. "Security" misunderstood.

Comment: Not sure it's about security @JulianReschke. It's my understanding that IE's policy is that if something isn't in the standards, then you shouldn't be able to do it. Which is an infuriatingly bad policy imho! But it's not because of security.

Comment: Well, it's relatively pointless to argue about, as it has been fixed quite some time ago.