# Which Browsers Support HTTP TRACE Method now?

Tags: security, http, browser, xss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fine Grained rest HTTP verbs browser support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218053/fine-grained-rest-http-verbs-browser-support)

Modern web browsers don't support TRACE method for security reason, but,for my network experiment, I want to know which browsers support HTTP TRACE method now.

After searched Wikipedia, I saw many different web browsers existing today (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser), but I am not sure which one support HTTP TRACE method.

[Update]

Erlend, I have a XMLHttpRequest (which employs a TRACE method) in an input box of a web page, then send it to my web server. I am not sure if it can be done by a text-based browser.

Makholm, a browser sends a TRACE request(of course, generally speaking ,browsers just use GET and POST), then a web server responses the request. If the web server doesn't recognize the verb(TRACE), it will response with a 405 Method Not Allowed status code or a 501 Not Implemented status code. Anyway, TRACE isn't just a property of the HTTP server, which need be supported both web browser and web server.

Comment: Huh? Support for TRACE is not a property of the browser but of the HTTP server.

Comment: Do you really need to run it from a browser? Couldn't you just connect to the port via telnet, and run the HTTP method manually? Or maybe try http console?