# Is this jQuery AJAX post saving data incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/users',
        data: {
            _method : 'PUT',
            user : {
                guides : {
                    step1 : true,
                    step2 : true
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Is this saving correctly? I want this json data in a rails serialized field but It's saving incorrectly as follows below which is causing errors.

User.guided:

```
--- "{\"step1\"=>\"true\", \"step2\"=>\"true\"}"
```

Then when I do the following in the rails view:

```
guides = [<%= current_user.guides.try(:html_safe)%>];
```

It outputs with `=>` instead of the expected `:`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907910/how-do-i-put-data-to-rails-using-jquery

Comment: sheikh-heera put is accounted for above...

Comment: I have the user.guided field set to serialize in the model... I'm saving the data with a JSON post mentioned in the question above. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could try to use JSON.stringify() otherwise jQuery will use $.param() to serialize your data. But your main issue is that you want a JSON string, and not the YAML that is generated. As far as I now something like

```
guides = [<%= current_user.guides.to_json %>];
```

should do the trick. Also, maybe I'm not 100% sure but you probably don't need to use html_safe on this, because it's already escaped, although can't tell how it will be rendered in view