# How do I send a put request for Ruby on Rails via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been googling but I can't seem to get the right setup, through the things I've seen on google I ended up with this:

```
var dataString = $('#markerform').serialize();
        var id = $('#route_id').val()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  '/routes/'+id,
            data: { "_method":"put", dataString},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

And this for my routes controller

```
def update
    @route = Route.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        if @route.update_attributes
            format.html
            format.json { render text: "Done" }
        else
            format.json { render text: "Bad" }
        end
    end
end
```

But I end up with this firebug error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid object initializer
[Break On This Error]   

data: { "_method":"put", dataString},
```

How might I clean this up so I can get some success going through this app. Thanks.

Comment: `type: 'PUT'` should work

Comment: @jvnill but I read it's not all browser compatible and I want to make sure I'm compatible the whole way across :)?

Comment: not sure about that.  but in order to fix your error, you should append the additional data to the serialized attributes. if I remember correctly, dataString will be a string so just add the _method to it like `dataString + '&_method=put'` and just pass it to data like `data: dataString`

Comment: @jvnill could you look at my controller and tell me why it's giving me a 500 error on submit?

Comment: @jvnill nevermind, fixed it, I was missing (params[:route]) from the update_attributes

Comment: ah cool. so what fixed your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (※Use `serializeArray` instead of `serialize`):

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url:  '/routes/'+$('#route_id').val(),
        data: $('#markerform').serializeArray(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var dataString = $('#markerform').serialize();
        var id = $('#route_id').val()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url:  '/routes/'+id,
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: but I read it's not all browser compatible and I want to make sure I'm compatible the whole way across :)?

Comment: The PUT method comes in XHTML2.0 version. however you can pass it via $.ajax as it will just go as a parameter and your server will handle method type PUT like now.

Comment: But I'm receiving the error listed at the bottom of my post, I think I have the wrong formatting of the data: any idea what's causing it?

Comment: As you have mentioned Type, please remove "_method":"put", and try again.

Answer (score -1):

It's been answered over at [How do I PUT data to Rails using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907910/how-do-i-put-data-to-rails-using-jquery#907974). Basically, Rails lets you do PUT calls (& any others that are unsupported) by doing a POST but adding a "_method" parameter with a value of "PUT".